# Dynamically Remove Select Options If Value Doesn't Equal a Certain Number

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I need to remove all of the options in a dropdown that don't have a specific value. Here's my code:
`

```
      <select name="worker">        
        <option value="0">John Doe</option>
        <option value="5">Jim Smith</option>
        <option value="6">Jane Doe</option>    
      </select>
```

`

I'm in wordpress, and basically need to say, "If the current user is 5 (Jim Smith), then only show him in the dropdown. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the php code that generates the dropdown:

```
/* Workers */

    $workers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM " . $this->workers_table . " " );

    $html .= '<label>';

    $html .= '<span class="title">'.__('Provider', 'appointments'). '</span>';

    $html .= '<select name="worker">';

    // Always add an "Our staff" field

    $html .= '<option value="0">'. __('No specific provider', 'appointments') . '</option>';

    if ( $workers ) {

        foreach ( $workers as $worker ) {

            if ( $app->worker == $worker->ID ) {

                $sel = ' selected="selected"';

            }

            else

                $sel = '';

            $html .= '<option value="'.$worker->ID.'"'.$sel.'>'. $this->get_worker_name( $worker->ID, false ) . '</option>';

        }

    }

    $html .= '</select>';

    $html .= '</label>';
```

Comment: do you need something bulletproof, or will Javascript suffice?

Comment: "If the current user is 5 (Jim Smith), then only show him in the dropdown" Well, how do you know current user?

Comment: I'd have to use the wordpress get_current_user_id() function and assign it to a jquery variable

Comment: Do you prefer to manipulate the dropdown server side before sending it to the browser? And if so, can you show the piece of code where that dropdown is generated?

Comment: I just added the portion of the code that generates that drop down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jquery [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) method to remove all the item which is not matching a certain value using [`attribute not equal selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

```
var removeItemVal="5"; 

$('#selectId').find('option[value!="'+removeItemVal+'"]').remove();
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/U6JGn/132/)

Comment: This is opposite of what OP is trying to do :)

Answer (score 2):

In case that you are not using jQuery, you can use `querySelector()` for selecting the select element and `.removeChild()` for removing the dirty `option` elements.

```
var userId = 5;
[].slice.call( document.querySelector('select[name="worker"]').children )
        .forEach(function(elem) {
            if ( elem.value != userId ) 
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); 
        });
```